# Can I use JMeter to load test a citrix application?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, citrix

I have an upcoming citrix project which needs to be load tested. Is JMeter a good choice for citrix applications? Is there any other open source tools like gatling available for load testing citrix applications?

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2020, you can use this [new JMeter plugin](https://github.com/blazemeter/CitrixPlugin)

It allows recording, replaying and performance testing Citrix exposed applications.

It can be installed using jmeter-plugins-manager:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=citrix

To see how to install it:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easily-manage-jmeter-plugins/

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: The link to the book doesn't point to a book.  Points to the plugin.  I'm trying to learn JMeter, so I was looking forward to finding out which book I should be using.  Any chance you could fix it so I knew which book?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the link.